# JPA, playframework, select order by before group by

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa

How can I write a query in "JPA" 
that will ORDER BY before the GROUP BY?

For example :

```
select m from Message m where m.id = (
  select distinct m2.conversation_id
    from Message m2
   where m2.from = 100 or m2.to = 100
)
group by m.conversation_id order by m.date desc
```

I want the last (most recent) messages for each conversation id.

Comment: did you find solution of this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Succinctly, you can't put the ORDER BY before the GROUP BY; SQL requires the ORDER BY after the GROUP BY.

However, you can achieve the result you require - either using the long-winded method below or by structuring your query with a different ORDER BY clause:

```
ORDER BY m.conversation_id, m.date DESC
```

In the code that fetches the data from the DB, you select the first row for each new conversation ID that is returned.

As always, I build the query in stages.  First, find the most recent message timestamp for each conversation ID that involved 'user ID 100':

```
SELECT m2.conversation_id, MAX(m2.date) AS date
  FROM Message AS m2
 WHERE m2.from = 100 OR m2.to = 100
 GROUP BY m2.conversation_id
```

Now, join that with the original table to get the rows of interest:

```
SELECT m1.*
  FROM Message AS m1
  JOIN (SELECT m2.conversation_id, MAX(m2.date) AS date
          FROM Message AS m2
         WHERE m2.from = 100 OR m2.to = 100
         GROUP BY m2.conversation_id
       ) AS m3
    ON m1.conversation_id = m3.conversation_id AND m1.date = m3.date
 ORDER BY m1.date DESC;
```

Comment: ok i think i got so far with native sql ,but i got an error for the m1.* (is it not a mistake?) ,after removing it i got this error now "IllegalArgumentException occured : org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: ( near line 1, column 44 [SELECT m1 FROM models.Message AS m1 JOIN (SELECT m2.conversation_id, MAX(m2.postedAt) AS postedAt FROM models.Message AS m2 WHERE m2.userFrom = ? OR m2.userTo = ? GROUP BY m2.conversation_id ) AS m3 ON m1.conversation_id = m3.conversation_id AND m1.postedAt = m3.postedAt ORDER BY m1.postedAt DESC ] "

Comment: also with native sql i was able to get what i wanted by surrounding the sql with a [select * from (the inner select with the order by ) group by postedAt] , but i didn't know the syntax the surrounding sql with JPA , thank you

Comment: Since I've no clue about what JPA is/does (beyond it is related to Java given the tag), for the specifics of that, you will need to consult elsewhere.  For the SQL, I think most DBMS support the notation 'SELECT m1.* FROM Message AS m1 ...', though it may be that standard SQL does not mandate it.  Since you didn't identify the DBMS, I can't help much more.  However, if your DBMS does not like the syntax, then you'll have to modify it slightly.  Possibly you need to list 'SELECT m1.conversion_id, m1.date, ...' or possibly you need to drop the 'AS' or ... get inventive.